# python datastructure(set like) that throws exception upon adding duplicates

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm looking for a data-structure that will throw exception upon adding duplicated element.

The closest thing I found is `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter as counter
>>> c = counter()
>>> c.update("A")
>>> c.update("A")
>>> c
Counter({'A': 2})
```

Which I can later query.

Is there a way to achieve directly what I'm looking for?

Comment: How is `Counter` any closer than a standard `dict`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want a counter or just something that works like `set`, but raises an error?  If it is the latter, you can subclass `set` and override the `add` method.

```py
class MySet(set):
    def add(self, x):
        if x in self:
            raise KeyError(f'Value already exists')
        super().add(x)

    def update(self, x):
        return self.__ior__(x)

    def __ior__(self, x):
        if any(xx in self for xx in x):
            raise KeyError(f'Value already exists')
        return super().__ior__(x)


s = MySet([1,2,3])
s
# returns:
{1, 2, 3}

s.add(4)
s
# returns:
{1, 2, 3, 4}

# trying to add an existing values raises an error.
s.add(4)
# raises
KeyError: 'Value already exists'
```

Edit: added additional methods

Comment: Probably would want to similarly override `update()` and `__ior__` (the magic method for `|=`)

Comment: Ok, added additional methods

Comment: Haha, leaving it as an exercise would have been fine too, as long as someone knows those methods exist :).